# Jquery - showing and hiding multiple divs

Tags: jquery

Im trying to learn some javascript/jquery, but im not making very much progress..

I have multiple divs like this :

```
 <div class="article1" style="display:none;">content</div>
 <div class="article2" style="display:none;">content</div>
 <div class="article3" style="display:none;">content</div>
```

Under each class i have a text link, once clicked on it i want it to show the specific div.

Like this :

```
<a href="javascript:toggle(1);" class="showarticle">View Article</a>
```

So i thought i'd make a function that i can give an ID, and shows the div on click, this is what i tried :

```
<script>  

            function toggle( id ) {
            $(".showarticle").click(function()){
               $(".article" + id).show();
                }    
            } 

</script>
```

However nothing happens, but i can't see anything wrong..

could someone tell me what im not doing right here?

Thanks

edit : i have included jquery library ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you use an event handler.

Event handlers are loaded once and then sit quietly in the background, waiting for something to trigger them. In your case, you want to load a `click` hander (after the DOM is loaded) that waits for a click on a link.

Something like this. HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="showarticle">View Article</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {            // wait for DOM to load
    $(".showarticle").click(function(e) { // click handler for all .showarticles
        e.preventDefault();               // cancel normal click behavior
        $(".article" + this.id).show();   // if id="1", shows '.article1'
    });
});
```

---

That's the 'minimal-changes' version. Best practices would be to use `data-` attributes instead of IDs on the link, and IDs instead of classes on the divs, and a stylesheet to hide them all at the start.

CSS:

```
.togglediv {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="article1" class="togglediv">content</div>
<a href="#" data-togglediv="article1" class="showarticle">View Article</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {            // wait for DOM to load
    $(".showarticle").click(function(e) { // click handler for all .showarticles
        e.preventDefault();               // cancel normal click behavior
        $div = $('#'+$(this).data('togglediv')); // http://api.jquery.com/data
        $div.show();                      // or $div.toggle() to show and hide
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/sT6gw/

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you click one of those `a` tags, you bind the `click` event to the `.showarticle` but you don't perform the action, one way would be this:

```
function toggle( id ) {
  $(".article" + id).show();
}
```

you should use id's instead of classes for this.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript version could be something like as shown below, need to assign unique id's to each div:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == "inline") {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(e.style.display == "none") {
        e.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fix the markup to look like this: (removed the number from the class, removed the markup javascript function)

```
<div class="article" style="display:none;">content</div>
<a href="#" class="showarticle">View Article</a>
<div class="article" style="display:none;">content</div>
<a href="#" class="showarticle">View Article</a>
<div class="article" style="display:none;">content</div>
<a href="#" class="showarticle">View Article</a>
```

Then just do this: fixed syntax, removed adding click handler each click, simpler code.

```
$(".showarticle").click(function () {
     $(this).prev(".article").show();
 });
```

EDIT: also NOW, it you want to hide previous shown, only showing the most recently clicked:

```
$(".showarticle").click(function () {
    $('.article').hide();
    $(this).prev(".article").show();
});
```

EDIT: Another way to toggle: assumes those are the only 'article' and 'showarticle' classes on the page

```
$(".showarticle").click(function () {
    $('.article').hide().eq($('.showarticle').index(this)).show();
});
```